# create timer (count down/ count up) on odoo

Tags: timer, odoo

I want to create timer in odoo view which support run/pause something like Soccer match time , min:sec format

I tried below code but it generated an error

```
@api.one
def timer_th(self):
    timer_thread = Thread(target=self.timer)
    timer_thread.start()

def timer(self):
    while self.current_time <= self.duration:
        time.sleep(1)
        self.current_time += 1
```

it gave me AttributeError: environments error

but when I used the code without thread it works but gui wasn't responsive

Answer (score 0):

if you want to schedule a piece of code you can use ir.cron model
this is for automating actions but i don't know if you can do start/pause thing

more details in the docs:
http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/odoo/models/ir.cron.html